# While editing one page in Drupal 7 it gives 500 error

Tags: drupal-7

I have lots of data in one Drupal page. I can view that page properly. But when I want to edit it for adding more data it gives below error.

> This page isn’t working
>   site is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I can edit and view all other pages, but only this page creates problem.

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error. Look into Server logfiles for more informations. Also stop using *ASAP* on SO

Comment: look at bottom, is it have any type of redirection which remove it from actual url

Comment: sorry to ask but where I can find Server logfiles? and that page edit is working on one server but fails on another server. I have checked .htaccess file and settings.php file also. I didn't find any difference between them.  And URL is also right.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: "_where I can find Server logfiles_" - it depends on your OS, so that's not currently answerable here. That question is something you can use a search engine for anyway. For Linux hosts, it is usually `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, but it can still vary.

Comment: There is no error in error.log file. Only php notices "PHP Notice:  Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in .." are there.

Comment: I got the answer. I had to change max_allowed_packet variable in mysql. Thanks everyone to answer my question. This was my first question on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly just the fact that you have so much data on that page. Viewing takes less memory, so the site can handle that, but editing takes more.

Try:

1. Increasing your memory limit (if you have access to that):
   Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and under the [mysqld] section add the line:
   `max_allowed_packet=500M`.
2. If the page is a view, disable "auto preview" so you can edit the view without having to load all the data every time.